# Error: Currently `save` requires model to be a graph network. Unable to save model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am using **google colaboratory** to implement deep learning in python3. I create a model, train it, test it. Everything is fine. Finally I try to save the model on my google drive. But is says 
***Error: Currently 'save' requires model to be a graph network.***

Upto training and testing there is no problem.

Then I mount the drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

And then try to save the model for later use as:

```
model.save('my_model_name.model')
```

But it is not saving the model. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

the preferred way to save a model with tensorflow is to use the `tf.train.Saver()` module. so lets say your model is simply called **Model** and you want to save it in a particular directory. This is the preferred way to do it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
directory_to_save = '/content/drive'
with tf.Session() as sess
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    #train model
    saver.save(sess, directory_to_save)
```